# Create three function to call Today, Yester and Future in PHP

Tags: php

I am a new PHP student . I want to create 3 functions to return Today, Yesterday, and Future.

Could anyone tell me how to create those?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP manual? It tells you how to make a function, which is easy, and how to get the date. Just combine the two

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer about what you want to return. When is 'Future'?

Comment: asked by a person with this "I am PHP expert." in their profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these function :

```
// midnight second or equal today
    function isToday($time) 
    {
        return (strtotime($time) === strtotime('today'));
    }

    //Yesterday

    function isPast($time)
    {
        return (strtotime($time) < time());
    }

    // Next day
    function isFuture($time)
    {
        return (strtotime($time) > time());
    }
```

Comment: spoon feeding helps no one

Comment: Please also note that attribution is required ([CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) for code samples from elsewhere.